# Find If a Variable Is Set in Java

Tags: java

I am making a command for an IRC Bot in Java using the Pircbot framework.

```
if (message.contains("!goawaybot")){
    String[] parts = message.split(" ");
    //use the parts variable to find if the command has an argument
    //if yes, part with that message, else:
    partChannel(channel, "Leaving");
}
```

If there is an argument, (i.e; "!goawaybot derp") then it should part with that argument as a reason (i,e; "derp"). Otherwise, it will part with a generic "Leaving" message.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: I think it's fairly clear OP is trying to extract an optional chunk of text after the string `!goawaybot` is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your requirements:

> `message` may contain the text "*!goawaybot*".  If it does, call `partChannel()` using any text following `!goawaybot` as the argument to `partChannel()`, or "*Leaving*" if none is provided.

Splitting on whitespace is problematic; not the least of which it makes it unnecessarily difficult to handle multi-word messages.

This is a standard problem for [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).  Define a regular expression, something like:

```
^.*!goawaybot(.+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If `message` matches this regular expression, use the value of Group 1 (if it exists) for your `partChannel()` message.

E.g.

```
final Pattern GO_AWAY_BOT = Pattern.compile("^.*!goawaybot(.+)?$");

...

Matcher m = GO_AWAY_BOT.matcher(message);
if (m.matches()) {
  partChannel(channel, m.group(1) != null ? m.group(1) : "Leaving");
}
```

Comment: I was looking for "message may contain !goawaybot _**at the beginning**_". The rest of your answer should work. Thanks.

Comment: In that case simply remove the `.*` from the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

`String reason = (parts[1] != null) ? parts[1] : "Leaving";`

and use `reason` instead of "Leaving" in the part command.

Comment: If the split doesn't contain a second token, this code will throw an exception because `parts[1]` will be out of array bounds.